# help unconfirmed for a day

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

hi can someone help I forgot to send fee one time is there anyway to speed up

https://blockchain.info/tx/fb4840af0ad51804eb8975d7e0afacd2e2c176748e98de502a9ffd19ed46d53b

thankyou

Comment: looks like your tx was confirmed a while ago.